# Kotlin: Is it possible to make a function, which calls a retrofit service, to return a String value?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Fragment and a View Model.

The layout of the Fragment contains a button.

When the button is clicked, we try to get an API response, which contains a url.

That url is used to start an intent to open a web page.

I am currently accomplishing this with event driven programming.

1. The button in the Fragment is clicked.
2. The function in the view model is called to get the API response, which contains the url.
3. The url in the view model is assigned as live data, which is observed in the fragment.
4. The fragment observes the url live data has changed. It attempts to launch the WebView with the new url.

Can the Fragment skip Observing for the url and directly get the ViewModel function to return a string?

Here is the code for the Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    
    // Set the OnClickListener
    myButton.setOnClickListener {
        myViewModel.getUrlQueryResults()
    }
    
    // Observables to open WebView from Url
    myViewModel.myUrl.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let{
            if (it.isEmpty()) {
                // No Url found in this API response
            }
            else {
                // Open the WebView
                try {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(it))
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                catch (e: Exception) {
                    // Log the catch statement
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the code for the ViewModel:

```
    // Live data observed in fragment. When this changes, fragment will attempt to launch Website with the url
    private val _myUrl = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val myUrl: LiveData<String>
        get() = _myUrl
    
    // Possible to make this return a string?
    fun getUrlQueryResults() {
        InfoQueryApi.retrofitService.getInfo(apiKey).enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                try {
                    // Store the response here
                    apiResponse = parseInfoJsonResult(JSONObject(response.body()!!))
    
                    // Grab the url from the response
                    var urlFromResponse = apiResponse?.url
                    if (urlFromResponse.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        urlFromResponse = ""
                    }
    
                    // Store the urlFromResponse in the live data so Fragment can Observe and act when the value changes
                    _myUrl.value = urlFromResponse
    
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    // Log catch statement
                }
            }
    
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                // Log error
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Retrofit has an adapter for coroutines (since 2.6.0): https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05 so you can use that and then your getUrlQueryResults() function becomes a suspending function. In your fragment launch a coroutine (Dispatchers.IO) and when you have the result (as a string). use withContext(Dispatchers.Main) to update the ui

Comment: to add  to above comment, there's many ways to return the value, getUrlQueryResults could return LiveData, a Flow or an RxJava Single depending on what you prefer

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin There is no need to use `Dispatchers.IO` when invoking suspend functions.

Comment: can you show me retrofitService.getInfo(apiKey) your this method?